# rest-client extension: Is it possible to break long URLs into multiple lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

I am using REST client extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client

Is there any way to break long urls into multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to keep `HTTP/1.1` just after the last param on the same line.

```bash
@base = http://localhost:8080

@param1 = 10
@param2 = something
@param3 = true
@param4 = 0

### 
GET {{base}}/test
?param1={{param1}}&param2={{param2}}&param3={{param3}}
&param4={{param4}} HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I think the webserver takes the second line as the continuation of the http url. rest-client does not concat the two lines.

Comment: Hi @AllanXu  I don't understand what you mean. Can you provide a code example in your question and the expected result please?

Comment: I mean rest-client sends the request to the HTTP endpoint as is with no changes. I was looking for option to have rest-client  changes the request URL and concatenate multiple lines.

Comment: I think your only option would be something like`@line1=xxx`, `@line2=xxx`, then just `{{line1}}{{line2}}`. But I doubt that is what you want to achieve.